How do i fix my flutter app which keeps crashing?
I've built my app in Debug, Release, and Profile, but each time I install it and launch it on my device, on my Android phone, it keeps crashing and returning back to the home screen. I've even installed it on other devices to see if it's a device problem, but it keeps happening. It's integrated with Firebase for the backend, and I have crashlytics dependency, but I don't see any crashlytics. I've set up the crashlytics very, very well. I don't see any crashlytics messages to even diagnose the problem, so what other options do I have to fix this crashing problem?
So for the release build, I tried creating the ProGuard rules, the file for the ProGuard rules and the R8 rules, and I also temporarily commented out the MinifyEnabled to false to determine if it's not a ProGuard issue. I also went through my dependencies one by one to add the necessary permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file. I also checked to both my app level build.gradle file and my project level build.gradle file to see if I was using any outdated dependencies, and if I had brought all native Android dependencies. I've configured them correctly in the app level build.gradle file. I also updated my dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file.
